# How clear do we have to be about the use of a term to ask a question that contains it?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

> > ```
> > According to Confucius, can non-virtue be learned ...
> > ```
>
> [This is](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3404/how-to-get-away-from-what-have-you-found-out-so-far-comments-but-also-not-conf) an interesting idea, but it seems like we first need to (a)
>   know whether virtue can be learned, (b) know what Confucians would
>   mean by non-virtue, and (c) know what they would mean by learning.

I think this hits upon an important point.

How clear do we have to be about the use of a term to ask a question that contains it? Is it enough to know the general definitions of 'learning', and have a vague idea of how it appears in the work asked about, to ask about what can be "learned"?

Answer (score 1):

We are all here to learn. You can ask questions with about any level of background knowledge.

Sometimes, people may respond to the context of the question and not to the question itself, when it seems that a misunderstanding has arisen in the context, leading to your question.

Most important is to be clear about what you know. Answerers need to identify the exact problem to give a relevant response, and providing context and showing what you know is vital for this.

Comment: hm well i think the 2nd paragraph makes sense, though it's not very helpful. do i list everything i've read confucius say on virtue, to ask the question properly? i tried to state everything i've read which has a bearing on *learning* virtue, but was then told it was a bad question, as i was grouping together quotations without proof that they answered the question. i can't ask questions anymore, anyway

Comment: @user3293056 just imagine asking a real person your question. What would you say? Don't worry if the first version of your question is not clear enough. That's what the comments are for, to help understand the problem. You can always edit the original post to add more details. It may take a few edits and comments before it is good, and that's fine. Eventually, you'll get the hang of it. Also, when a question is put on hold that is not the end. You just discuss a bit what is needed to make the question more clear and then it can be reopened.